# In R version 4, Anova fails to compare linear mixed regression base model to other models with different variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, anova

I was working with R version 3.6.3 and recently updated to version 4.0.3. I have given an example of the model I am working on.

```r
Model0 <- lmer(accuracy~Temperature+Relative_Humidity+scaledweek+(1 | pxids),data=ptrails.df)
Model1 <- lmer(accuracy~CO+Temperature+Relative_Humidity+scaledweek+(1 | pxids),data=ptrails.df)
Model2 <- lmer(accuracy~pm10+Temperature+Relative_Humidity+scaledweek+(1 | pxids),data=ptrails.df)
Model3 <- lmer(accuracy~NO+Temperature+Relative_Humidity+scaledweek+(1 | pxids),data=ptrails.df)

anova(Model0,Model1,Model2, Model3)
```

The idea is for each model to compare with the base model (`Model0`) to determine which variable has a significant effect.

Example of output:

[image]

I do not get the p-value for Model2 and Model3. This wasn't the case in the previous version. I tried to compare model0 with model1 and then model0 with model2 etc. such comparisons give me the p-value however, I have very large data, I would need to do it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little bit of a guess because you haven't provided a reproducible example, but this probably has to do with versions of `lme4` (not R) before and after version 1.1-24: the [NEWS file for lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/news.html) reports that

> anova() now returns a p-value of NA if the df difference between two models is 0 (implying they are equivalent models)

"df difference" means the difference in the numbers of parameters estimated. There are two ways that different models could have equal numbers of df:

- the models are actually equivalent (although their parameters may have been specified differently, e.g. if `f` and `g` are factors then including `f*g` and `f:g` give different parameterizations but an equivalent model fit. In this case the change in deviance ("Chisq") also be zero. This appears to be what's happening in models 0 vs 2 in your case (although it puzzles me that `npar` is different: hard to understand without a reproducible example. Perhaps you added a perfectly correlated predictor, or your model fit was singular?) In this case it could be argued that the p-value is 1, but `NA` is also reasonable (see this [discussion](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/583))
- the models are **non-nested**, for example one model includes numeric covariate `A`, the second model includes numeric covariate `B`. This is not a case that occurred to the package developers ... In this case **the likelihood ratio test is inappropriate**, so it doesn't make sense to return a p-value at all.

If you want to compare non-nested models you either need something like Vuong's test, or just compare the AIC values. (I would argue that `bbmle::AICtab()` gives a more useful format for comparison ...)

Comment: Thank you Ben Bolker for your help!

Comment: if this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...

Comment: I tried to install bbmle from github and I am unable to install. It says that not available for version 4. Or am I searching at the wrong place?

Comment: `remotes::install_github("bbolker/bbmle")` ? But you shouldn't need the development version, you could just `install.packages("bbmle")` to get it from CRAN